# How to catch WM_MBUTTONDOWN in CTreeControl

Tags: c++, winapi, tree, mfc, window-messages

I have a window with `CTreeControl`. I am able to catch `WM_MBUTTONDOWN` event in area of window (`ON_WM_MBUTTONDOWN` macro), but not in area of `CTreeControl`.
Is some way to catch this event for `CTreeControl`?
Thanks.

Comment: I believe you will have to use an [`ON_CONTROL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc#on_control) entry in the control parent's message map.

Comment: Do you have some exmaple? I have not idea how to use it... Thanks.

Comment: Using SpyXX, I don't see any obvious messages the tree control sends back to its parent. And that ON_CONTROL macro is for handling WM_COMMAND notification messages like BN_CLICKED and such. You'll likely need to subclass the tree control to handle the WM_MBUTTONDOWN directly.

Comment: In this discussion he derives his on tree control: https://microsoft.public.vc.mfc.narkive.com/X5490dmy/tree-control-onclick-vs-onlbuttonup and then handles `OnClick`.

Comment: @EdDore `ON_CONTROL` is for arbitrary messages. `ON_COMMAND` is for `WM_COMMAND`-based messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a MFC class that inherits from CTreeCtrl and then create WM_MBUTTONDOWN from the class wizard.

[image]